# Seleccionar itemes

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app y una parte de lo que tengo que hacer es que pueda seleccionar el estado y el municipio en el que se encuentra el usuario se puede decir que quiero usar un tipo select box y en uno venga los estados y en otro los municipios pero quiero que aparezca el municipio dependiendo el estado por ejemeplo
selecciono Coahuila y que me aparezcan nada mas los municipios de ese estado y si selecciono otro estado me aparezcan sus municipios.... Pienso utilizar spinner pero estoy atorado en lo de que solo aparezcan los municipios dependiendo su estado

Comment: Considera agregar más datos a tu pregunta, trata de ser más especifico , agregar tu código por ejemplo en el caso que al seleccionar un elemento ùnicamente aparezcan sus elementos relacionados puedes encontrar ejemplos en el sitio. revisa [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay 2 formas en como puedes lograrlo:

`ArrayAdapter<String>` se utiliza para agregar opciones a los spinners con un array de string donde cada elemento del array es un elemento del spinnner. Cargarías las provincias en base al indice seleccionado:

```
 Spinner estadosSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.estados_spinner);
    final Spinner provinciasSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.provincias_spinner);

    ArrayList<String> estados = new ArrayList<String>();
    estados = obtenerEstados();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, estados);

    // le asignamos el adapter al spinner
    estadosSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        estadosSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        //cargas las provincias por el indice del estado seleccionado
                        ArrayList<String> provincias = cargarProvinciasPorPosicionEstado(position);

                        // Aqui inicializas el adaptador con las provincias
                        ArrayAdapter<String> provinciasAdapter = new ArrayString>(ActivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, provincias);
                        provinciasSpinner.setAdapter(provinciasAdapter);
                    }
              @Override
              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

               }
        });
```

[Aquí un tutorial mas detallado](https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/android-spinner-dinamico-en-android-provincias-y-localidades-de-espana/) y en [Proyecto Simio tienen otro muy bueno](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-spinner-i/)

**Adapter personalizado**

Esta es que por cada elemento de un array con un tipo de dato propio, cargas una vista y le asignas la data a la vista con cada elemento del array:

Esta clase representa tanto los estados como las provincias:

```
public class Localizacion
{
    private String nombre;
    private int id;


    public String getNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String name)
    {
        this.nombre = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Creamos una vista `localizacion.xml` que representa una localización visual tanto para los estados como las provincias también:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/nombre"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Ahora creamos nuestro propio ArrayAdapter que cargaría cada elemento del spinner:

```
public class SimpleSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

        // localizacion reprenseta un estado o prinvincia
        private ArrayList<Localizacion> localizaciones;
        public PersonAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Localizacion> localizaciones) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2 );
            this.localizaciones = localizaciones;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            // preguntamos si la vista es null para cargar la vista desde el xml
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.localizacion, parent, false);
            }

            TextView nombre=  convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);

            // Guardamos la data de la localizacion para al momento de seleccionar, podamos extraer cual fue
            convertView.setTag(this.localizaciones.get(position));
            nombre.setText(this.localizaciones.get(position).getNombre);


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Ahora en el activity, tenemos que asignar la data de las localizaciones al adapter y agregar el evento `setOnItemClickListener` y cargar las provincias según el estado que se seleccione. Se le asigna el mismo adapter a ambos spinner ya que son iguales:

```
Spinner estadosSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.estados_spinner);
final Spinner provinciasSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.provincias_spinner);

ArrayList<Localizacion> estados = new ArrayList<Localizacion>();
estados = obtenerEstados();

SimpleSpinnerAdapter adapter = new SimpleSpinnerAdapter(this, estados);
estadosSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
estadosSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                // obtenemos la localizacion que guardamos en el adapter en la propiedad tag
                Localizacion estado = (Localizacion)view.getTag();

                //cargas las provincias por el indice del estado seleccionado
                ArrayList<Localizacion> provincias = cargarProvinciasPorEstado(estado.getId());

                // Aqui inicializas el adaptador con las provincias
                SimpleSpinnerAdapter provinciasAdapter = new SimpleSpinnerAdapter(ActivityActual.this, provincias);
                provinciasSpinner.setAdapter(provinciasAdapter);
            }
});
```

[En proyecto simio tiene un tutorial](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-listview-adapter-personalizado-i/)  que puede ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas Gracias si me sirvio, nomas una pregunta antes del activity del spnner tengo un activity de un menu el del menu sempre aparecia primero y ahora empieza el activity del spinner